# CPU Stress Test Using Non-GUI Tool Or PowerShell Script For Windows 2016/2019/2022

Tags: windows-server

I am trying to automate CPU stress testing on Windows Servers 2016, 2019, and 2022. I would like to test CPU at certain percentages e.g. 70/80/90% I would also like a non-ui based solution so that the tests could be automated.

I found and have been using the [CpuStres](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/cpustres) tool, but this is GUI based. I'm looking for a similar tool or a PowerShell Script that I could use so that no interaction is required.